# want to iterate through a hierarchy in XML using DOM

Tags: java, xml

I am trying to iterate through this XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Document>
    <Sitemap>
        <TreeMap>
            <RootNodes>
                <TreeMapNode>
                    <NodeType>Folder</NodeType>
                    <NodeValue>fwreference_war</NodeValue><!--component name=project name-->
                    <ChildNodes>
                        <TreeMapNode>
                            <NodeType>Folder</NodeType>
                            <NodeValue>education</NodeValue><!--packegeName=nodevalue.title-->
                            <ChildNodes>
                                <TreeMapNode>
                                    <NodeType>Folder</NodeType>
                                    <NodeValue>editorsample::Mapping</NodeValue><!--title=mapping ; name=editorsample-->
                                    <ChildNodes>
                                        <TreeMapNode>
                                            <NodeType>PackageHandle</NodeType>
                                            <NodeValue>01::inquiry::list</NodeValue><!--sceenName::screenmode::screentype-->
                                            <ChildNodes />
                                        </TreeMapNode>
                                    </ChildNodes>
                                </TreeMapNode>
                            </ChildNodes>
                        </TreeMapNode>
                    </ChildNodes>
                </TreeMapNode>
            </RootNodes>
        </TreeMap>
    </Sitemap>
    <Mastermap>
        <TreeMap>
            <RootNodes />
        </TreeMap>
    </Mastermap>
    <Pages />
    <Masters />
</Document>
```

**1) I want to extract the values of every `<NodeType>` inside `<sitemap>`.**

**2) When I am trying to iterate from `<sitenode>` but when I am trying to find child nodes then the result comes is given below:**

```
 NodeList headerList = doc.getElementsByTagName("Sitemap");
    NodeList childNodeList=headerList.item(0).getChildNodes();
    //gives 3
    NodeList headerList = doc.getElementsByTagName("TreeMap");
    NodeList childNodeList=headerList.item(0).getChildNodes();
    //gives 3
    NodeList headerList = doc.getElementsByTagName("RootNodes");
    NodeList childNodeList=headerList.item(0).getChildNodes();
    //gives 3
    NodeList headerList = doc.getElementsByTagName("TreeMapNode");
    NodeList childNodeList=headerList.item(0).getChildNodes();
    //gives 8
```

How to iterate over this hierarchy and why above three tags is giving same no. of child Nodes i.e.3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close to solving it. You can iterate over the children and check if it's a `Node.ELEMENT_NODE`.

The reason your elements have 3 children is because it has mixed content. There are some whitespaces and a new line before the tag. So basically every node has list of `[Node.TEXT_NODE, NODE.ELEMENT_NODE, Node.TEXT_NODE]`

Comment: I just want to say why its not counting all the sub tags inside it ? And as <sitemap> is giving only 3 child then how it will iterate over all the nodes?

Comment: The child nodes does not include all descendants. For this you have to check the child nodes and get their children again.